# How to check if DateTime lies within String times?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @CurDate datetime,
    @Begintime nvarchar(10),
    @Endtime nvarchar(10)

SELECT @CurDate = GETDATE()
SELECT @Begintime = '9:00 AM'
SELECT @Endtime = '5:00 PM'
```

What is the best way to check if the CurDate lies within the given times? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL Server **2008** and higher, you can convert your current time, and the begin and end times (as `nvarchar`) into `TIME` variables and then do the check:

```
DECLARE @CurrTime TIME = CAST(@CurDate AS TIME)
DECLARE @TimeFrom TIME = CAST(@Begintime AS TIME)
DECLARE @TimeTo TIME = CAST(@Endtime AS TIME)

SELECT 
    @CurrTime, @TimeFrom, @TimeTo,
    CASE 
        WHEN @CurrTime BETWEEN @TimeFrom AND @TimeTo THEN 'Yes!'
        ELSE 'No, sorry'
    END
```

Comment: Question: If TimeFrom = '8:00 PM' and TimeTo = '4:00 AM' will this code still work? (It seems to not)

Comment: @user1026110: no, it cannot work - since you *only* have the time, between 8pm and 4am is kinda "impossible" - in that case, you'd have to start using the **full** date and time.

Comment: @user1026110: in that case, you'd have to write `WHERE @CurrTime > @TimeFrom OR @CurrTime < @TimeTo` or something like that

Comment: I don't think that would work exactly since since 6:00 PM > TimeFrom and ignore the fact that it is also > TimeTo. 

Perhaps in this case I can swap the TimeFrom and TimeTo values and say NOT BETWEEN?

Comment: My thinking is that BETWEEN 8:00 PM AND 4:00 AM is the same as saying NOT BETWEEN 4:00 AM AND 8:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `DATEDIFF` to calculate the hours and minutes difference.
Here -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

I wouldn't use use `nvarchar`, but instead of it use something like this:

```
@BeginTime = DATEADD(hour, 9, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,getdate()))) 
@EndTime = DATEADD(hour, 17, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,getdate())))
```

The condition to use can be:

```
WHERE @CurDate BETWEEN @BeginTime AND @EndTime
```

Best regards,